# How to put function using string control

Tags: javascript, html, intel, intel-xdk

[image]

On this first Image I would like to declare a variable that is string that would be used for making a condition if the username that is input if the string has 5 numbers it would be tag as EmployeeID if string has 10 numbers it would be tag as studentID.

[image]

So that before I create another app for User Interface for Employee and Student it would then evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able deduce the code language, but I will write down a function considering that it's a jQuery.

```
var Id = "" , type = "";
if($("#Userid").val().length = 5)
{
     Id = $("#Userid").val();
     type = "employee";
}
elseif($("#Userid").val().length = 10)
{
     Id = $("#Userid").val();
     type = "student";
}
else
{
     alert("Invalid ID");
}
```

Hope that's help! Now you can check `type` variable to decide the type of current logged in user.